# Collection Sort not working with custom ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I want to present my list in sorted form. I know one way to do it is using the `Collections` class and invoke the `sort` method. I tried that but it's not working on an `ArrayList` with my custom class as object.

I tried to use to this method:

```
Collections.sort(nameOfAmimals);
```

This is my code:

```
package com.example.hp.learning;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class A_Animals extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a__animals);


        ArrayList <Animal> nameOfAmimals = new ArrayList<>();

        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Cat" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Dog" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Bird" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Lion" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Squirrel" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Gray Wolf" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Snake" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Beer" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Deer" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Donkey" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Rhinoceros" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Raccoon" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Rabbit" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Kangaroo" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Koala" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Octopus" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Parrot" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Swan" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Yak" , ""));
        nameOfAmimals.add(new Animal("Zebra" , ""));

        AnimalArrayAdapter animalArrayAdapter = new AnimalArrayAdapter(A_Animals.this , nameOfAmimals);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_animals);
        listView.setAdapter(animalArrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you custom object implements Comparable, or create a Comparator and use the overloaded version of Collection.sort

Answer (score 2):

Java simply does not know how to sort your custom class.

You have two options:

1. Let your `Animal` class implement [`Comparable<Animal>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and add a [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) method:

   ```
   class Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {
       String name;

       public Animal(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return this.name;
       }

       @Override
       public int compareTo(Animal o) {
           return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Provide a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to the [`Collections#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method:

   ```
   Collections.sort(animals, Comparator.comparing(Animal::getName));
   ```

   Or the old-fashioned Java 7 way:

   ```
   Collections.sort(animals, new Comparator<Animal>() {

       @Override
       public int compare(Animal o1, Animal o2) {
           return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
       }

   });
   ```

Both options will sort animals by their name (or whatever property you choose).

Comment: If  i use this line of code it gives me error by using method 2    
        Collections.sort(nameOfAmimals , Comparator.comparing(Animal::getAnimalNameInEnglish));    Error : Error:(93, 71) error: method references are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)

Comment: Any reason you cannot use Java 8? Anyway, I've updated my answer and included the way for Java 7 as well.